# About sandbox instagram

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

thank you for your attention.
I was reading about the instagram sandbox and there were some doubts, maybe some of you have already used this feature and can answer me, my doubt is.

- So that I can retrieve for example the photos of any user, will that user have to give permissions to my app?
  Ex: I would like to search through the api of instagram, my friend's latest midia. Does he have to accept any permission for this? Even being a public account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have get your app reviewed and approved by Instagram for `public_content` scope permission, and go live mode, then you can make API call and access any public user's photos, you dont need permission from that user.

You cannot access other user's data in sandbox mode, you can invite other user to your sandbox and if he accepts then you can access that user's latest 20 photos only.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, my doubts have been clarified. I would like to '' close the post '' so that other users do not need to respond again, how do I? thank you again!